# Moovit Integration Causes Crash

Tags: ios, swift, url, crash, fatal-error

Im trying to implement Moovit into my app so users can easily get transit directions to a place.

However I'm encountering some difficulties...

## Updated Code:

```
func openMoovit(To : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "moovit://")!) {
        // Moovit installed - launch app (with parameters)
        let MoovitURL: String = "moovit://directions?dest_lat=\(To.latitude)&dest_lon=\(To.longitude)&dest_name=\(barNameTemplate))&auto_run=true&partner_id=<TestApp>"
        let escapedString = MoovitURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: escapedString!)!)
        }else {
// Moovit not installed - send to store
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id498477945")!)
```

which is the basic from the [Moovit iOS API](https://www.developers.moovitapp.com/deeplinking-your-app)

and then simply called the function when i **press a button** :

```
let MoovitButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Moovit", style: .default) { action -> Void in
                
self.openMoovit(To : self.CoordinatesTemplate)// calling function
print("Moovit Chosen!")
```

This code is working well with Waze integration but fails with Moovit...
When i press the button it crashes **at line** :

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: MoovitURL)!)
```

**saying :**

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

I'v added moovit into my Plist as well , so i don't know what is causing the crash...Did i miss anything?

i would really appreciate if anyone could help me solve this, Thanks ahead.

Comment: `URL(string: MoovitURL)!` can't make the URL object so you can verify by `printing print(URL(string: MoovitURL))`

Comment: Specifically you need to urlencode your URL; it contains a space that needs to be converted to %20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work,

Due to space in your string `Times Square`, it is unable to make URL object:

```
func openMoovit(To : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "moovit://")!) {
         // Moovit installed - launch app (with parameters)
         let MoovitURL: String = "moovit://directions?dest_lat=40.758896&dest_lon=-73.985130&dest_name=Times Square&orig_lat=40.735845&orig_lon=-73.990512&orig_name=Union Square&auto_run=true&partner_id=<TestApp>"
         var escapedString = MoovitURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
         UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: escapedString)!)
    }
```

Comment: Ok so it opens Moovit now but it doesn't start the direction for some reason... look updated code above in the question , you already solved my problem it didn't open Moovit but if its not too much to ask can you look at this one too? thanks.

Comment: Okay, I am looking

Comment: `(To.latitude)&dest_lon=\(To.longitude)` check this I think may be it is an optional value so you have to unwrap it...

Comment: Even the Example Moovit Gives itself doesn't work : `"moovit://directions?dest_lat=40.758896&dest_lon=-73.985130&dest_name=Times Square&orig_lat=40.735845&orig_lon=-73.990512&orig_name=Union Square&auto_run=true&partner_id=<TestApp>"`

Answer (score 1):

Converting urlString to `URL` is returning `nil` and you are forcefully unwrapping `nil`. Due to that it's crashing.

You should check `nil` before unwrapping

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "moovit://")!) {
       // Moovit installed - launch app (with parameters)
       let MoovitURL: String = "moovit://directions?dest_lat=40.758896&dest_lon=-73.985130&dest_name=Times Square&orig_lat=40.735845&orig_lon=-73.990512&orig_name=Union Square&auto_run=true&partner_id=<TestApp>"
       if let url = URL(string: MoovitURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
       }
}
```

And Don't forgot to add your parter id in your url.